# Read arbitrarily json data to a javafx treeview,and only show the first element of any array in it

Tags: json, javafx, treeview, gson

I need to show a json file on a javafx treeview,the structure of the json is unknown.Like the web site:  [json viewer site](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/)
I show the tree for user to select path of a value(like xpath of xml),so if the json is too big,I only need to show the first element of any array in json.

for example,the original data is:

```
{
    name:"tom",
    schools:[
        {
            name:"school1",
            tags:["maths","english"]
        },
        {
            name:"school2",
            tags:["english","biological"]
        },
    ]
}
```

I want to show:
[image]

again:the structure of json is unknown,it is just one example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no other option than recursively handling the json and create the `TreeItem` structure based on the element info.

(There's probably a better way of adding the symbols, but I didn't find appropriate icons.)

```
private static final String INPUT = "{\n"
        + "    name:\"tom\",\n"
        + "    schools:[\n"
        + "        {\n"
        + "            name:\"school1\",\n"
        + "            tags:[\"maths\",\"english\"]\n"
        + "        },\n"
        + "        {\n"
        + "            name:\"school2\",\n"
        + "            tags:[\"english\",\"biological\"]\n"
        + "        },\n"
        + "    ]\n"
        + "}";

private static final Image JSON_IMAGE = new Image("https://i.stack.imgur.com/1slrh.png");

private static void prependString(TreeItem<Value> item, String string) {
    String val = item.getValue().text;
    item.getValue().text = (val == null
            ? string
            : string + " : " + val);
}

private enum Type {
    OBJECT(new Rectangle2D(45, 52, 16, 18)),
    ARRAY(new Rectangle2D(61, 88, 16, 18)),
    PROPERTY(new Rectangle2D(31, 13, 16, 18));

    private final Rectangle2D viewport;

    private Type(Rectangle2D viewport) {
        this.viewport = viewport;
    }

}

private static final class Value {

    private String text;
    private final Type type;

    public Value(Type type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public Value(String text, Type type) {
        this.text = text;
        this.type = type;
    }

}

private static TreeItem<Value> createTree(JsonElement element) {
    if (element.isJsonNull()) {
        return new TreeItem<>(new Value("null", Type.PROPERTY));
    } else if (element.isJsonPrimitive()) {
        JsonPrimitive primitive = element.getAsJsonPrimitive();
        return new TreeItem<>(new Value(primitive.isString()
                ? '"' + primitive.getAsString() + '"'
                : primitive.getAsString(), Type.PROPERTY));
    } else if (element.isJsonArray()) {
        JsonArray array = element.getAsJsonArray();
        TreeItem<Value> item = new TreeItem<>(new Value(Type.ARRAY));
       // for (int i = 0, max = Math.min(1, array.size()); i < max; i++) {
        for (int i = 0, max = array.size(); i < max; i++) {
            TreeItem<Value> child = createTree(array.get(i));
            prependString(child, Integer.toString(i));
            item.getChildren().add(child);
        }
        return item;
    } else {
        JsonObject object = element.getAsJsonObject();
        TreeItem<Value> item = new TreeItem<>(new Value(Type.OBJECT));
        for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> property : object.entrySet()) {
            TreeItem<Value> child = createTree(property.getValue());
            prependString(child, property.getKey());
            item.getChildren().add(child);
        }
        return item;
    }
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
    JsonElement root = parser.parse(INPUT);

    TreeItem<Value> treeRoot = createTree(root);
    TreeView<Value> treeView = new TreeView<>(treeRoot);
    treeView.setCellFactory(tv -> new TreeCell<Value>() {
        private final ImageView imageView;

        {
            imageView = new ImageView(JSON_IMAGE);
            imageView.setFitHeight(18);
            imageView.setFitWidth(16);
            imageView.setPreserveRatio(true);
            setGraphic(imageView);
        }

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(Value item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);

            if (empty || item == null) {
                setText("");
                imageView.setVisible(false);
            } else {
                setText(item.text);
                imageView.setVisible(true);
                imageView.setViewport(item.type.viewport);
            }
        }


    });

    final Scene scene = new Scene(treeView);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: Great!That is what I need.I probably thought of how to write, but did not write it out.But I wonder how did you make the brackets and curly brackets?Icons or symbols?But I can`t find the symbols.  And If only read the first element of array,maybe it is more in line with the question.

Comment: I couldn't find the symbols anywhere so it used your screenshot and adjusted the viewport to display the appropriate part of that image. Not the best solution and you probably should create your own images or use some `Shape`s (`Text`/`Rectangle`) to be sure not to violate any copyright...

Comment: If I want to add a check box to the tree items,and still showing picture,what shall I do?

Comment: Modify the `TreeCell` implementation. This is a new question though that cannot be answered properly in a comment.

Comment: @fabian this is great , well done .