# how to represent JSON as treeview in Javafx

Tags: json, javafx

I have a Film model like below:

```
public class Film{
    private String name;
    private String category;
    private Actor[] actors;
    private MarketingPlan marketingPlan; 
}

class Actor{
    private String name;
    private double salary;
}

class MarketingPlan{
    private String nameOfPlan;
    private Country[] affectedCountries;
}

class Country{
    private int countryID;
    private String marketingText;
}
```

which generate a JSON like this:

```
{
  "name": "My First Film",
  "category": "action",
  "marketingPlan": {
    "name": "plan1",
    "affectedCountries": [
      {
        "marketingText": "This is a marketing text",
        "countryID": 332
      }
    ]
  },
  "actors": [
    {
      "name": "John",
      "salary": 123456
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to represent my JSON result above as tree structure in JavaFX. Can anyone give me some hint or suggest me some tutorial how can I do it. Thank you very much in advanced!

Comment: Did you check the API documentation already? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TreeView.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51039132/read-arbitrarily-json-data-to-a-javafx-treeview-and-only-show-the-first-element